# How to select a window of values from the list?

Tags: python, list

I have a stream of data which is of the type

```
list  = [22 , 15 , 6 ,12 ,30 , 45, 200 , 238 , 220 , 6000, 6250 , 6900, 6700,6500, 0 , 250 , 6000 ,6800,220, 250,200]
```

As you can see the stream of data has some very high values in the middle which is what we desire to extract. This block can also contain low values (0 and 250 in the above list) but definitely higher values at the start and end of block ( 6000,6500). How can we extract this particular window of data.

The output should be

```
new_list = [6000,6250,6900,600,6500,0, 250 , 6000 , 6800]
```

I usually work on MATLAB. So the way i would do this is by finding the first and the last peak in the data

Comment: Can you define "peak"? Number >= 6000? Number higher than x% of items?

Comment: What is your criteria for identifying the window? A certain width from the highest value|median|mode?

Comment: i mean i cannot hardcode it to be a certain value like above 6000.

Comment: one way would be to use the standard deviation of your list:
Then lets say take a peak as a value > 2 * std.  You could do that on the absolute values or on the slope. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html

Comment: If you can't hard-wire it, you need to specify what you would use instead.

Comment: what I was thinking of basically is to iterate till I reach a certain percentage increase , and continue iterating till i reach a certain percentage decrease from maximum value

Comment: and instead of this "certain percentage" you could use the standard deviation of your slopes. Might be still not perfect sure worth a try

Comment: Then why would your window include 0? Surely 6500 to 0 is a large percentage decrease. In any event, once you specify a criterion it will probably be easy enough to code; but only you can specify the criterion since we don't know what you are trying to do with all this.

Comment: @JohnColeman "till I reach a certain percentage increase" which means I may not encounter zero at all since I am not moving inside my desired block

Comment: @the_reaper If you like Matlab, the `numpy` package for python is very very similar to Matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could establish a treshold between the highest and lowest values in the data, then find the first and last indexes of entries that are over the treshold to form a range in the list:

```
data     = [22 , 15 , 6 ,12 ,30 , 45, 200 , 238 , 220 , 6000, 6250 , 6900, 6700,6500, 0 , 250 , 6000 ,6800,220, 250,200]
treshold = (min(data)+max(data))/2
start    = next(i for i,v in enumerate(data) if v >= treshold)
end      = len(data) - next(i for i,v in enumerate(data[::-1]) if v >= treshold)
result   = data[start:end]

print(result)
# [6000, 6250, 6900, 6700, 6500, 0, 250, 6000, 6800]
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a plot of your data:

[image: plot of points without line]

The traditional way to do what you're talking about would be to interpolate the data. This means adding a curve of best fit, such as a ***cubic spline***.

[image: plot with line]

After finding a differentiable curve passing through the points, you find the first derivative (rate of change). Wherever the first derivative has a local maximum is where your data suddenly went uphill or downhill.

However, all of that maybe overkill for your purposes. I think the following code will do what you want:

```
class OnOffRecorder:
    """
    """
    def __init__(self, is_active = False):
        """
        By default, is not recording data
        """
        self.is_active = is_active
        self.data = dict()

    def turn_recording_on(self):
        self.is_active = True

    def turn_recording_off(self):
        self.is_active = False

    def toggle_recording(self):
        self.is_active = not(self.is_active)

    def push(self, key, value):
        if self.is_active:
            self.data[key] = value
        return

    def pop(self):
        old_data = self.data
        self.data = dict()
        return old_data

def get_peak_data(data, delta):
    """
    `delta` represents percentage distance between
            minimum and maximum of the data.

            if data suddenly increases by delta, then begin recording
            if data suddenly decreases by delta, then stop recording
    """
    mind = min(data)
    maxd = max(data)
    raynge = maxd - mind
    # `li` == `left index`
    # `ri` == `right index`
    record = OnOffRecorder()
    record.turn_recording_off()
    for li in range(0, -1 + len(data)):
        ri = li + 1
        ld = data[li] # left data
        rd = data[ri] # right data
        if abs(rd-ld)/raynge > delta:
            if rd > ld :
                record.turn_recording_on()
            elif rd < ld:
                record.turn_recording_off()
        record.push(ri, rd)
    return record.pop()

data = [22 , 15 , 6 ,12 ,30 , 45, 200 , 238 ,
        220 , 6000, 6250 , 6900, 6700, 6500,
        0 , 250 , 6000 ,6800,220, 250, 200]

# if data suddenly increases, then begin recording that data
# if data suddenly decreases, then stop recording that data.
delta = .25
peak_data = get_peak_data(data, delta)
print(peak_data.values())
```

### EDIT:

I developed a second/different approach which does not require you to manually specify a `delta` value. This is described below:

1. Sort the data.
2. traverse the sorted data from minimum to maximum
3. record differences/jumps.
4. find maximum of the jumps.
5. That maximimum jump is where low signals transition to high signals

Below is code which implements the step-by-step process outlined above:

```
def get_dividing_line(data):
    sdata = sorted(data)
    jumps = [sdata[i+1] - sdata[i] for i in range(0, -1 + len(sdata))]
    jumps_max = max(jumps)
    jumps_max_left = jumps.index(jumps_max)
    jumps_max_right = [x for x in reversed(jumps)].index(jumps_max)
    jumps_max_right = len(sdata) - jumps_max_right
    jump_start = sdata[jumps_max_left]
    jump_end = sdata[jumps_max_right]
    return (jump_start + jump_end)/2

def get_high_signals(data):
    threshold = get_dividing_line(data)
    return [x for x in data if x >= threshold]

data = [22 , 15 , 6 ,12 ,30 , 45, 200 , 238 ,
        220 , 6000, 6250 , 6900, 6700, 6500,
        0 , 250 , 6000 ,6800,220, 250, 200]

high_signals = get_high_signals(data)
print(high_signals)
# prints [6000, 6250, 6900, 6700, 6500, 6000, 6800]
```